# Installing u-customizer (live cd editor, dependant on gambas2) on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, customizer

I am trying to install u-customizer from [here](http://u-customizer.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu). When I install it with gdebi, it says:

Error: Dependency not satisfiable: gambas2-gb-desktop.

Now, neither can I find any other version of u-customizer to install, nor from where to install gambas2.

How do I install gambas2 or u-customizer?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that is an old, outdated version of U-Customizer from 2012; its new website is https://github.com/kamilion/customizer and the latest version can be downloaded from there.